# Facebox plugin onClick do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, database

I am using the [facebox plugin](http://defunkt.io/facebox/)  for a link I have, but I also want to do something onClick.

[image]

I tried doing onclick event :
**(I am using literal to do it, maybe this is the problem)**

```
litWorkplaceButton.Text = "<a class='google-button' href=\"#dialog-form\" id='btnSaveForLater' rel='facebox' onclick=\"addSaveList\" runat='server'>Save for later</a>";
```

but the following error appears:

```
'addSaveList' is undefined
```

and I define my method as `void protected addSaveList(){}`

I just want to save the Project's ID on a table, so I need to code behind the page!

I tried to use a literal for `<asp:LinkButton>` (on code behind) and normal and the error result showed me this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="searchLinkk" runat="server" onclick="searchLink_Click">Search</asp:LinkButton>

<a id="CPHcontent_searchLinkk" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$CPHcontent$searchLinkk&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Search</a>
```

The one that was normally was converted to an  tag with an href="javascript:__doPostBack"

But I have to use literal because i show this button only if an event is occured(user is logged in).

Is there another way to do it, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the `a` tag you are inserting into the page via the `Literal`'s `Text` property is not recognized as a server control.  The `OnClick` attribute is being recognized as a javascript event.

You can still use your `LinkButton` and simply set the `Visible` property on it if the user is not logged in.  Put something like this in your code behind's `Page_Load` method:

`searchLinkk.Visible = User.IsAuthenticated;`

Comment: I tried also LinkButton but I my facebox doesn't works! It needs a href and a rel in order to work!

Comment: You can manually set those attributes either directly in the markup, or programmatically with `.AddAttribute("rel","...")`. Server controls, if they don't recognize an attribute, simply forward it into the generated html.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're misunderstanding the purpose of the Literal control. It's meant to be used only to inject text/html into the page, it cannot be used to dynamically add a server control. For that, you should use the Placeholder control.

You get the `'addSaveList' is undefined` error because when the browser sees the "onclick" attribute (which should not be used for SO many reasons), it tries to bind it to a global Javascript method called `addSaveList`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't use inline JS, its bad semantics, which will always come back to haunt you. Instead, put the script in a separate script file, link to it in your header, and have it contain this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Put your method here

});
```

Good Luck,
-Brian

Comment: I want my method to connect with my database, I want an SqlConnection!